# 06 chevy trailblazer vibration and humming in front end

Tags: frontend

06 chevy trailblazer. vibration and slight humming sound in front end starting at 30mph getting louder with speed of vehicle but engine speed dont matter, have shifted into neutral same sound. gets alot louder over 50mph . at first thought it was just went turning to the left or going straight which led me to believe it as passenger side wheel bearing, ( replaced that no change) but now I noticed I hear the vibration no matter left or right turn or straight ahead. can feel slight vibration in brake pedal and thru steering wheel. sound kinds of reminds me of a truck running real rough knobby tires.

Comment: Check the tires for cupped wear.  And further check the front shocks/struts for proper damping.